# work with jmktime in JDF library

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, timestamp, mktime

I have a problem with converting Jalali date to timestamp. For do that i'm using JDF library. So far I've Done this:

```
$jalalidate = $this->input->post('c_adddate');
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', $jalalidate);
$timestamp = jmktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

But it always show the current time!

```
echo date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Just Shows the current time.